# session variable error asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

Suppose i have 2 pages  'A' and 'B'. i set a session variable in 'A', that is checked in page_load function in page 'B' using:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["x"].ToString()))
 {
 }
```

and the appropriate actions are performed based on the value of that session variable but if I open page 'B' first , it gives the error:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How do i set the instance of this object beforehand itself?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exception before the `IsNullOrEmpty` comes in to action and parameter passed to `IsNullOrEmpty` is evaluated. You will get the exception By calling `ToString()` on `Session["x"]` if `Session["x"]` is null. So you will get exception before the call to `IsNullOrEmpty` is made.

*Change*

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["x"].ToString())) {} 

To

if(Session["x"] != null && Session["x"].ToString() != string.Empty) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Session["x"].ToString()` when `SessionX` is null that's why you are getting `null exception`
 So you should check that `Session["x"]` should not be `null`

```
if(Session["x"] != null )
{
  // your code
}
```